# Setting Windows Environment Variable in install4j

Tags: install4j

I am trying to set an environment variable for my program.
i.e. MY_HOME = c:\MyProgramDirectory
So far I haven't found the answer.

One more thing I am trying to install a service, how do i set the name of the service.
It is coming same as the executable. i.e MyProg.exe. I would like something like "My Useful Service" in name field. The description is coming ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip: Do not ask two different questions in a single question on stackoverflow.

> I am trying to set an environment variable for my program. i.e.
>   MY_HOME = c:\MyProgramDirectory So far I haven't found the answer.

Use the "Modify an environment variable on Windows" action for that. The installation directory can be referenced in the text field of the "Value" property like this: `${installer:sys.installationDir}`.

> One more thing I am trying to install a service, how do i set the name
>   of the service. It is coming same as the executable. i.e MyProg.exe. I
>   would like something like "My Useful Service" in name field.

The "Install a service" action has a "Description" property for that.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked. I will recommend Install4J to my company :)